# Using <br> instead of <p> in Summernote?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wysiwyg, summernote

Needed to use `<br>` tag in the summernote editor instead of `<p>` while user clicks on the Enter button, so here is my code:

```
var $this = $(this),
    box = $('textarea.CommentsFields');
box.summernote({
    height: 100,
    focus: true,
    toolbar: [
        [ 'all', [ 'bold', 'strikethrough', 'ul', 'ol', 'link' ] ],
        [ 'sided', [ 'fullscreen' ] ]
    ],
    callbacks: {
        onEnter: function(){
            box.summernote('insertNode', document.createTextNode("<br>")); 
            console.log('uiwdbvuwecbweuiuinsjk');
        }
    }
});
```

I wrote a custom callback of the onEnter event, when the user hit the return button it raises a callback, and write the `<br>` tag which is not what I am looking for.

[image: result screenshot]

I read their documentation but can not understand how to stop the default action of the enter button and write `<br>` tag instead of wrapping the element in `<p>` tag.

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: try this: https://github.com/summernote/summernote/issues/546

Comment: I think they changed the module/plugin architecture in the latest release and it didnt works

Comment: You have a workaround [at this reply](https://github.com/summernote/summernote/issues/702#issuecomment-130561422).

Comment: Summernote blows now, becoming the bane of my existence at work after upgrading to version 8+

Answer (score 11):

This code worked for me:

```
$("#summernote").on("summernote.enter", function(we, e) {
     $(this).summernote("pasteHTML", "<br><br>");
     e.preventDefault();
});
```

This interceps the Enter press event and changes its default behaviour, inserting a `<br>` instead of a new paragraph.

Comment: Great solution! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to change or fix the summernote library itself, you can use the `shortcut keys` for adding a line break.

- Use `Shift + Enter` for giving a line break.
- Use `Enter` for changing a paragraph, as `summernote` add a `div`/`p` to start a new line when you press `Enter`.

Hope this works.

Answer (score 1):

There appear to be [at](https://github.com/summernote/summernote/issues/676) [least](https://github.com/summernote/summernote/issues/1334) [10](https://github.com/summernote/summernote/issues/1776) [or](https://github.com/summernote/summernote/issues/2538) [so](https://github.com/summernote/summernote/issues/3435) [bugs](https://github.com/summernote/summernote/issues/702) [filed](https://github.com/summernote/summernote/issues/546) about this over at SummerNote, with no fix or plan to fix it unfortunately.

Fortunately you can fix it in a sneaky way, that is going to be pretty brittle to future versions - so upgrade carefully. You Monkey Patch it:

```
$.summernote.dom.emptyPara = "<div><br/></div>";
box.summernote(options);
```

The first line is the fix - the Monkey Patch. I included the second line, where SummerNote is initialized, just to demonstrate you MUST do your Monkey Patch before you start SummerNote - or the Monkey Patch will not make it in and you'll still get p tags on enter.

Answer (score 1):

Guaranteed 2 liner & **no plugin**:

```js
$.summernote.dom.emptyPara = "<div><br></div>"; // js
```

```css
.note-editor .note-status-output{display:none;} /*css*/
```

Comment: As div is already a block element, why add a br element? won't it just break 2 lines instead of one?

Answer (score 0):

Today summernote has no way to do what you want. You can check https://github.com/summernote/summernote/issues/702, so, the only way is to create your own pull-request with fixed logic for different paragraph style.

Comment: Yes, thats why i am not trying to delete the parent <p> tag. so the idea is there should be only one p tag.

Comment: hey are you find any solution For This issue? I have a same issue

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

Replace (in Summernote.js line 3786)

```
    if (event.keyCode === key.code.ENTER) {
        context.triggerEvent('enter', event);
    }
```

in

```
    if (event.keyCode === key.code.ENTER) {
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**I encountered this problem and the solution is below.**

onKeydown function in callbacks solves your problems.

**Example**:

```js
$('.textarea-editor').summernote({
  height: 250, // set editor height  
  minHeight: null, // set minimum height of editor  
  maxHeight: null, // set maximum height of editor  
  focus: true, // set focus to editable area after initializing summernote  
  htmlMode: true,
  lineNumbers: true,
  codemirror: { // codemirror options
    theme: 'monokai'
  },
  mode: 'text/html',
  callbacks: {
    onKeydown: function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this javascript solved enter issues

```
$("#summernote").on("summernote.enter", function(we, e) {
     $(this).summernote("pasteHTML", "<br><x></x>");
     e.preventDefault();
});
```

using empty x - tag... it for dummy purpose tag....

100% working for me.. any doubt.. contact : prajeshkumar93@gmail.com